# pprint nested dictionary - identical to input

Tags: python, file, dictionary, save

I am trying to get python to read a dictionary and then modify it in some way (add/remove content) and then save it to another file.

The dictionary I am using is

```
kundenDict = {
'Kunde1': {
    'Datum11':{'ArtikelNo111':['Bezeichnung111', 'Farbe111', 'Kollektion111'],
               'ArtikelNo112':['Bezeichnung112', 'Farbe112', 'Kollektion112']},
    'Datum12':{'ArtikelNo121':['Bezeichnung121', 'Farbe121', 'Kollektion121'],
               'ArtikelNo122':['Bezeichnung122', 'Farbe122', 'Kollektion122']},
    },

'Kunde2': {
    'Datum21':{'ArtikelNo211':['Bezeichnung211', 'Farbe211', 'Kollektion211'],
               'ArtikelNo212':['Bezeichnung212', 'Farbe212', 'Kollektion212']},
    'Datum22':{'ArtikelNo221':['Bezeichnung221', 'Farbe221', 'Kollektion221'],
               'ArtikelNo222':['Bezeichnung222', 'Farbe222', 'Kollektion222']},
    },
'Kunde3': {
    'Datum31':{'ArtikelNo311':['Bezeichnung311', 'Farbe311', 'Kollektion311'],
               'ArtikelNo312':['Bezeichnung312', 'Farbe312', 'Kollektion312']},
    'Datum32':{'ArtikelNo321':['Bezeichnung321', 'Farbe321', 'Kollektion321'],
               'ArtikelNo322':['Bezeichnung322', 'Farbe322', 'Kollektion322']},
    },
}
```

I started using:

```
def pretty(d, indent=0):
   for key, value in d.iteritems():
      print '\t' * indent + str(key) + ": {"
      if isinstance(value, dict):
         pretty(value, indent+1)
      else:
         print '\t' * (indent+1) + str(value)
```

before I realized this will not give me the same output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at the builtin `pprint` module?

Comment: And why would you need to have the same output?

Comment: Like I said, I will modify the dictionary. With same output I mean the same format. Sorry I should have been clearer.--------- And yes I have looked at the pprint module. but how can I pprint to a file? Did I miss something? Sorry I am also fairly new to python. Thanks

Comment: I found out that using:`import pprint

logfile=open('C:\\Users\\tkruttsc\\Desktop\\dd'+'.txt', 'w')

pprint.pprint(kundenDict, logfile)
` seems to work to some extend although I am ten left with the content of the dict as a dict rather than a file containing the dict ie kundenDict = {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working using the following bit of code:

```
from pprint import pprint

masterDict = {Some nested dictionary}
f=open('masterDict.py','w')
f.write( 'masterDict = {\n')

def pretty(masterDict, indent=1):
    for key, value in masterDict.iteritems():
        f.write('   ' * indent + "'" + str(key) + "'" + ': {\n')
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            pretty(value, indent+1)
        else:
            f.write('    ' * (indent+1) + str(value) + '}\n')
    f.write('    ' * (indent+2) + '}\n')

pretty(masterDict)
f.close()
```